# How to set the "disabled" button back to "enabled" thru PHP?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, bootstrapping

I have two buttons like "Save" and "Create". Now my question is when the page is loaded, the "Create" button should "enabled" and the "Save" button is "disabled".

Now, if I click the "Create" button then the "Save" button should be "enabled" and "Create" button should now be "disabled".

```
//php code start
<?php
$isSaveDisabled = false;
if(isset($_POST['save']))
    {
        echo 'Hello robin';
        $isSaveDisabled = true;
    }
if(isset($_POST['create']))
    {
        echo 'Byeeee robin';
    }

?>
// php code ends
//bootstrap code start
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="BootStrap/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body >
        <div class="container jumbotron">

        <form action="" method="post">

            <div class="btn-group-xs">
            <button type="submit" id="btn1" name="save" <?php if ($isSaveDisabled) { echo 'disabled="disabled"';}?>>Save</button>
            <button type="submit" id="btn2" name="create">Create</button>

            </div>


        </form>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
//bootstrap code ends
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try it..

```
//php code start
<?php
$isSaveDisabled = true;
$isCreateDisabled=false;
if(isset($_POST['save']))
    {
        echo 'Hello robin';
        $isCreateDisabled=false;
    }
if(isset($_POST['create']))
    {
        echo 'Byeeee robin';
        $isSaveDisabled = false;
    }

?>
// php code ends
//bootstrap code start
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="BootStrap/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body >
        <div class="container jumbotron">

        <form action="" method="post">

            <div class="btn-group-xs">
            <button type="submit" id="btn1" name="save" <?php echo $isSaveDisabled?'disabled':''; ?>>Save</button>
            <button type="submit" id="btn2" name="create" <?php echo $isCreateDisabled?'disabled':'';?>>Create</button>
            </div>


        </form>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
//bootstrap code ends
```

Answer (score 0):

It can be done using jQuery.

Try this:

```
    $(document).on('click','#btn2',function(){
       $(this).prop('disabled',true);
       $('#btn1').prop('disabled',false);
    });
```

Comment: thanks sir but i want to use  enabled and disabled buttons only in php not using js, jquery and others.

Answer (score 0):

Include this in your HTML

```
<script>
 $(document).on('click','#btn2',function(){
       $("#btn2").prop('disabled',true);
       $("#btn1").prop('disabled',false);
    });
</script>
```

Also, include jQuery in you html.

Comment: this event would not trigger because the page will refresh

Answer (score 0):

use a if to test if the page was submitted with create to disable create

```
<div class="btn-group-xs">

            <?php $create,$save = ''; if(isset($_POST['create'])) {$create = 'disabled';} else {$save = 'disabled';}?>
            <button type="submit" id="btn1" name="save" <?php $save?>>Save</button>
            <button type="submit" id="btn2" value="create" name="create" <?php $save?> >Create</button>

            </div>
```